# Jquery 1.5 ajax sending as GET data on POST

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, codeigniter, autocomplete

(Sorry about my english, it aint my birth lang)
I have a project that uses codeigniter+JqueryUI. I was thinking about upgrading JQuery version to 1.5 mainly because I am using a lot of ajax calls, and any improvement in speed is highly appreciated.
So this is my code, wich works fine in JQuery version 1.4.4:

```
$("#nome_produto").autocomplete({
            source: function( request, response ) {
                $.ajax({
                    async:false,
                    url: "<?php echo site_url("produtos_produto/json_produtos/f") ?>",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: request,
                    success: function( data ) {
                        response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                            return {
                                label: item.label,
                                value: item.label,
                                cod: item.cod
                            }
                        }));
                    },
                    beforeSend:function(){
                        $("#nome_produto").toggleClass("loading");
                    },
                    complete:function(){
                        $("#nome_produto").toggleClass("loading");
                    }
                });
            },
            minLenght:3
        });
```

In Jquery 1.5, I got a 404 error, but the url requested is this:
http://myurl.com/produtos_produto/json_produtos/f?callback=JQUERY_hashofnumbers, even though this is a post request.
Does anyone knows why it happens?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

might be related to this ticket: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8084
the quick fix is:

```
  jQuery.ajaxSetup({ jsonp: null, jsonpCallback: null});
```

before doing ajax calls

Answer (score 2):

check for hidden redirects

in my case I am using Django, where, in general, all URL's end with '/'

If a request is made for a URL not ending in '/' and the resource cannot be found then Django issues a redirect to that same URL with '/' appended (It's a generally useful option in Django).

In my javascript I had accidentally omitted the trailing '/' in my POST request. This resulted in a redirect (to the correct url). However apparantly POST is automatically converted to GET during a redirect (see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/10586852/473285).