# Non www to www redirect rule stop posting form data as POST

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

In my PHP application, I have applied below rule to redirect non-www to www in htaccess.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

But after applying this rule, I got into a trouble.
System stop sending POST data. 
Login,registration etc all form have stop working after this rule.

Even I have tried to load login page with http://www.mydomain.com/login.html still it is not working.

How can i get rid of this situation?

Thank you.

Comment: read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586779/redirectmatch-changes-post-to-get) post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have everything pointing at domain with www. If in form you have as action parameter set `http://mydomain.com` it simple won't work. You need to change it to `http://www.mydomain.com`

Comment: oh it worked for me. So it means that if i have non-www url in form action parameter and apply rule for non-www to www, it redirect non-www to wwww and flush all my POST data.

Comment: Simple when you make redirection POST data are not transferred to new site. In fact I almost never user full path in action so you can have in action only `action='test.php'` and you don't have to worry if your domain is with www or not with www